# How do I always show saving dialog when user export csv file in Angular app?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, csv

I'm developing an Angular2+ app. One of the requirements is to export a csv file. When user clicks "Export" button, a csv file will be downloaded to user's computer. The app supports Chrome.

I noticed that a "save file as..." dialog pops up only when I turn on "Ask where to download before downloading" in Chrome settings. If not, a csv file will be downloaded straightaway to a (default) directory without asking user where to download it.

I want Chrome to show the save file dialog every time user exports a csv file.

How can I do this?
I have searched for a solution, but couldn't find any so far.

I'm using Angular2, typescript 2.2, xlsx and file-saver npm packages.
I am more than welcome to use different npm packages to solve the issue.

Update: Here is my code.

Csv export method in component:

```
public export(): void {
this.queryService.getSheet(this.sheetName)
    .subscribe((data: SheetView) => {
        try {
            const csvData = this.createRawData(data);
            if (csvData == null) {
                return;
            }

            // Export csv file
            if (!this.csvExportService.export(csvData, this.fileName + '.csv')) {
            console.log('error');
            }

        } catch (error) {
            // ...
        }
    });
}
```

createRawData() returns object array, something like this.

```
[{
  id: "abc123",
  name: "sheet 1",
  whenCreated: "2017-08-20",
  ...
  }, ...
]
```

CsvExportService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

type AOA = Array<Array<any>>;

@Injectable()
export class CsvExportService {

  constructor() { }

  public export(csvData, fileName: string) {
    if (csvData == null) {
        return false;
    }

    // Generate a worksheet and workbook, then add the worksheet to workbook
    const workSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(csvData);
    const workBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workBook, workSheet, 'Sheet1');

    // Save it to file
    const options: XLSX.WritingOptions = { bookType: 'csv', type: 'binary' };
    const workBookOut = XLSX.write(workBook, options);
    saveAs(new Blob([this.s2ab(workBookOut)]), fileName);
    return true;
  }

  private s2ab(s: string): ArrayBuffer {
      const buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
      const view = new Uint8Array(buf);
      for (let i = 0; i !== s.length; ++i) {
          view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
      };
      return buf;
  }

}
```

I can download a csv file with this code, but it does not show the save file dialog unless I turn on the option "Ask where to download before downloading" in Chrome settings.
I want to show the dialog regardless of the setting.
I don't know if it's possible, though.

Comment: Lets see your code, I do know there's a handy package that handles all of that, and the blob stuff. You have an API service to send the csv?

Comment: @TGarrett, I have added my code.